# How to modify the appearance of MD components

Tags: angular, angular-material

In this code:

```
    <button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
       <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
        <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
      </md-menu>
    </button>
```

I am trying to put `top: 67px;` I've tried this:

```
 <md-menu style="top: 67px;" #menu="mdMenu">
```

or in `<button md-menu-item`

---

But it has not worked, I can see that it is dynamically created, so

[image]

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" dir="ltr" style="left: 480px; top: 15px; pointer-events: auto;">
```

---

I modified `top` from the browser`top: 67px;`

[image]

and it works as I expect.

---

I tried to add in the `component.css` file the next:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    top: 67px;
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

I have also used it:

```
.test {
        top: 67px;
    }
```

and add in `class` but it does not work for me.

---

How can I modify the `top` In this component, by modifying the `.cdk-overlay-pane` or other way.

I'm sorry for my bad English. I hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried what's written in documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu ?

> Customizing menu position
>
> By default, the menu will display below (y-axis), after (x-axis), and overlapping its trigger. The position can be changed using the x-position (before | after) and y-position (above | below) attributes. The menu can be be forced to not overlap the trigger using [overlapTrigger]="false" attribute.

Using `[overlapTrigger]="false"` should work, at least with `y-position` set to `below`.

Comment: Yeah, I read that, and it seems that I'll have to use what you say, I've looked at `menu-directive` file and others and it seems that everyone works with` type MenuPositionY = 'above' | 'Below'; 'I wanted to be able to determine and say how many px was moving in y. Thanks for your time

Comment: I upvote your response and check. While, there is a solution to move certain px.